# @requestparam spring always is null

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, web-services

I try pass parameter to java spring and read with @requestparam, but it is always null.

This is my code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/prueba", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute Person person, @ModelAttribute Prueba prueba, Model model, @RequestParam String param) {

    System.out.println("/prueba");
    List<Prueba> lista = new ArrayList<Prueba>();
    Prueba p11 = new Prueba();
    p11.setNamePrueba("prueba1");
    Prueba p22 = new Prueba();
    p22.setNamePrueba("prueba2");
    lista.add(p11);
    lista.add(p22);
    model.addAttribute("prueba", new Prueba());
    model.addAttribute("lista",lista);
    System.out.printf("get param= %s \n",param);
    return "form :: selector";
}
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function cargaDatos(){ 
            var link = 'prueba';
            var param= $('#selector').val();
            //Llamada a la funcion que carga los datos en la base de datos.
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: param,
                url: "http://localhost:8080/prueba",
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Ejecutado correctamente");
                    alert(param);
                    $("#selectorDiv").load(link);
                },
                error: function (data){
                    alert("Error en la ejecucion");
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

what is the problem?, I don't save the value of selector in server

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cargaDatos(){ 
        var link = 'prueba';
        var param= $('#selector').val();
        //Llamada a la funcion que carga los datos en la base de datos.
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {"param" : param},
            url: "http://localhost:8080/prueba",
            success: function(data){
                alert("Ejecutado correctamente");
                alert(param);
                $("#selectorDiv").load(link);
            },
            error: function (data){
                alert("Error en la ejecucion");
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Also, need to add `value` attribute, like this: `@RequestParam("param")`

Comment: Not really, if explicit name is missing Spring defaults to name of parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much!. I dont need add value